# Dropdown for a bootstrapmodal from a ajax POST

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this bootstrap modal view:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add missed Tara or Harvest Product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="font-noraml">
            Select event type
          </label>
       <div class="input-group">
            <select data-placeholder="Select" class="form-control chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
              <option value="Tara">
                Tara Machine
              </option>
              <option value="Harvest">
                Harvest Product Machine
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="font-noraml">
            Product list
          </label>
       <div class="input-group">
            <select data-placeholder="Select" class="form-control chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
              <option value="ajaxdata">
                get here the ajax data
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to populate my Product list dropdown with options returned by my ajax in a JSON format, in order to do that, I have this button function when I load the modal:

```
function onAddMissedEntryInfoClicked(entryId) {
var currentEntryId = entryId;
$('#myModal').modal('show');  //this load modal view
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "Monitor/getHarvestProductsDropdown",
success: function(data) {
    $($.parseJSON(data.msg)).map(function () {
return $('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.label);
}).appendTo('#ajaxdata');
    console.log(data);
},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
}
});
}
```

Monitor/getHarvestProductsDropdown in the url is the function that returns the list from mysql.

This is how my console.log(data) is looking:

[image]

And this is the json I get:

```
[{"name":"Orz"},{"name":"Orz Baza"},{"name":"Porumb"},{"name":"Lucerna"},{"name":"Rapita"},{"name":"Sorghum"},{"name":"Orz Primavaratic"},{"name":"Orz Primavaratic Baza"},{"name":"Floarea Soarelui"},{"name":"Triticale"},{"name":"Triticale Baza"},{"name":"Grau"},{"name":"Grau Baza"}]
```

But how I can append that json list in my dropdown?

PS1. error:

> VM375:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Function.m.parseJSON (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:15998)
>       at Object.success (http://local.delta-rom.rrsolutions.ro/assets/js/my/monitor.js:244:13)
>       at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:27309)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:28122)
>       at x (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:22111)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.b (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:26030)

Comment: what is the error did you found in console?

Comment: Updated with the error!

Comment: You're trying to parse `data.msg` when your `data` is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax opts, set `dataType` to `'json'` as you expect json data from server. then iterate a loop and set your value.
Try the code below, and let me know the status.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType:'json',
url: "Monitor/getHarvestProductsDropdown",
success: function(data) {

    $('#ajaxData').empty();
    for(var i = 0; i< data.length;i++){

      $('#ajaxData').append('<option value="'+data[i]['name']+'">'+data[i]['name']+'</option>');
    }
    console.log(data);
},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
}
});
```

Comment: Right now is Product list dropdown is empty, and the console log return objects like this: http://i.prntscr.com/4e354d7ac5794fa0ab9b6e3404953b68.png Should I change something in my view ?

Comment: I missed `data[i]`. could you please try again with updated code?

Comment: Now all the products are in the same option, pic: http://i.prntscr.com/c4e42d80cfd8498ea1e206a20a8d7303.png

Comment: Ahhh, I solved, I was stupid on something, thank you so much sir!